# how to get data from one page to another without run the page in php

Tags: php, curl

I want to get some data from one page to another but I need to load only one page. I tried to use SESSION but it didn't work.

Page 1

```
<?php
session_start();
print $_SESSION["charge"];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/page2.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=admin&password=admin123");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

page 2

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["charge"]="Y";

    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("test") or die("Cannot connect to database");

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $exists=mysql_num_rows($query);

    $table_username = $table_password = $name = "";

    if($exists>0){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $table_username=$row['username'];
            $table_password=$row['password'];
        }
        if(($username==$table_username) && ($password==$table_password)){
            if($password==$table_password){
                print "Username & password is approved!";
            }
        }
        else{
            print "Incorrect Password!";
        }
    }
    else{
        print "Incorrect Username!";
    }
?>
```

I can't load page 1 without loading page 2. Is there anyway to get data from page 2 to page 1 without loading page 2 ?

Comment: without loading page 2 it's not possible.? and what do you really mean? without refreshing or without submitting or what else. if your page is not going to load how can you get any values from them

Comment: Can make an AJAX call to Page 2. But since Page 1 is already executed it will not reload the variable, so you can't make use of value in Page 1.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include more details about what you're trying to accomplish. What errors do you see?

Comment: I don't want to you SESSION i just tried it. just trying to get data from page2.php to page1.php. Is there any way to do that. I mean I don't want to display the content page2.php because there are some more code there

Comment: nevermind just say the update

Comment: It would be really helpful if you explained what you are trying to to do, as @Twisty said.  There are likely numerous ways, but without an explanation of why you are doing this, any answer would be just grasping at straws.   Please edit your original question with more information.

Comment: What data from page 2 are you trying to get?

Comment: I want to get that charge variable. Is there any way i can get that

Answer (score -2):

Is there anyway to get data from page 2 to page 1 without loading page 2?

I do not believe this is the anser you want.  It **IS** the answer to the question you asked.

```
Just go directly to http://localhost/page1.php
```

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of what the op's question is exactly, nor what you think his question is exactly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @HansZ.  Question:  Is there anyway to get data from page 2 to page 1 without loading page 2?  Answer:  
Go to directly  to `http://localhost/page1.php`